Is there any binding library in .Net Maui for the ML Kit Document Scanner Google Api?
I tested the ML Kit Document Scanner Api from Google on a native Android application and it worked.
Here the tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/doc-scanner/android?hl=es-419#kotlin
Is there any nuget package binding this library in .Net Maui?
dependencies {
   // …
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-document-scanner:16.0.0-beta1'
}


There is no wrapper for .Net Maui from Google on this. I am unaware if there are other solutions built on top of it.

I am also searching for that.

@Led Machine https://github.com/letscodewithkalyan/MauiMLKitDocumentScanner
Checkout this which i created bindings Library.
